# Indexing .tar.gz files in Solr 5.3.1: HTTP Error 405 POST not supported

Tags: solr

Under a Solr 5.3.1 installation with /update working as expected I tried to index a .tar.gz file with the update/extract query handler,

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/#/myfirstcore/update/extract?literal.id=adocument&commit=true" -H 'Content-type:application/octet-stream' --data-binary "@encapsulate.tar.gz"
```

But receive the following,

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/admin.html. Reason:
<pre>    HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Under the admin panel, the update/extract specification is

```
/update/extract
class:org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler
version:5.3.1
description:Add/Update Rich document
src:null
```

And solr was generally installed according to these directions: [Digital Ocean: Installing Solr 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.4](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-5-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Given the above error message how can I configure Solr to index zipped files (including .tar.gz)? The use case is to associate content with taxonomy metadata stored in json format by zipping them together. This way Solr will index both documents and associated taxonomy metadata together and follow on partial update commands are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution, change:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/#/myfirstcore/update/extract?literal.id=adocument&commit=true" -H 'Content-type:application/octet-stream' --data-binary "@encapsulate.tar.gz"
```

to

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/myfirstcore/update/extract?literal.id=adocument&commit=true" -H 'Content-type:application/octet-stream' --data-binary "@encapsulate.tar.gz"
```

And a query for id=adocument returns 1 hit. That it didn't pick up the fields is a separate issue.